# dijit.Tooltip --- how do you disable hover?

Tags: tooltip, dojo

I would like to have a tooltip that only comes up when you click a text link (but does nothing on hover). I know this is easy to do with jquery, but I have to use dojo. I've tried to declare a new tooltip class with "attachHover: false;" but it breaks when I declare the class so I assume this is wrong:

```
dojo.declare("clickTooltip", digit.Tooltip,  {
markupFactory: function(){
return new clickTooltip();
},
attachHover: false;
}
});
```

Please let me know if there is an easier way, or if you have any pointers to fix the above code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using a regular hidden div instead of the dojo package. Dojo isn't very easy to customize.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using the Tooltip widget,

```
require(["dijit/Tooltip", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/mouse", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Tooltip, dom, on, mouse) {
  var node = dom.byId('tooltip');
  on(node, 'click', function() {
    Tooltip.show("I am a tooltip", node);
  });

  on(node, mouse.leave, function() {
    Tooltip.hide(node);
  });
})
```

Working fiddle here,
http://jsfiddle.net/c4hp1L12/

Answer (score -1):

You could try the following from the [dijit demo page](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/themeTester.html):

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
    <span>User Login</span>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.TooltipDialog" id="tooltipDlg" data-dojo-props='
        title:"Enter Login information",
        execute: function(){ alert("Simple Alert!"); }'>
        <div dojoType="dijit.form.Form" id="myForm" jsId="myForm" encType="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
        <script type="dojo/method" event="onSubmit">return true;</script>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="user">User:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="user" id="user" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" required="true"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="pwd">Password:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" required="true"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <!-- End of dijit form -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know it's a button, but it does only work when you click it.